# How to interface GSM with 8051 microcontroller to send SMS?

Tags: gsm, 8051, at-commands

I am doing a project on SMS sending through GSM 
using SIM 900 module and 8051.

My code is:

```
#include<reg51.h>
unsigned char *command = "AT";
unsigned char *echo = "ATE0";
unsigned char *msgConfig = "AT+CMGF=1";
unsigned char *number = "AT+CMGS=\"8283******\"";
unsigned char *message = "hello";
unsigned char *CTRLZ = 0x1A;
void serial_init(void); 
void serial(unsigned char);
void puts(unsigned char *p );
void delay(void);

void main()
{
serial_init();  
puts(command);
delay(); // delay of approx 1 sec
puts(echo);
delay();
puts(msgConfig);
delay();
puts(number);
delay();
puts(message);
delay();
puts(CTRLZ);
while(1);

}
void serial_init(void)
{

TMOD=0x20; //timer 1, mode 2(8-bit autoreload) to set baud rate 
TH1=0xFD; //-3 to TH1 for 9600 baud rate
SCON=0x50; // 8 bit txion, 1 start 1 stop bit, REN enable for both txfr and rxve
TR1=1; // start timer
}

void puts(char *p)
{
char *temp = p; /*temp pointer so that the actual pointer is not displaced */
while(*temp != 0x00)
{
serial(*temp); 
temp++;
} 
}

void serial(unsigned char x)
{

SBUF=x;
while(TI==0);
TI=0;

}
void delay(void) // delay for approx 1 sec
{
int i;
TMOD=0x01; // timer 0 in mode 1
for(i=0;i<142;i++)
{
TL0=0x00; // starting value from 0 
TH0=0x00;
TR0=1; // sart timer
while(TF0==0); // polling TF flag for high
TR0=0; // stop timer
TF0=0; // clear flag TF0

}
}
```

The problem here is that the SMS has not been not sent by the GSM module.

When I use the calling function by replacing the AT commands, then calling works
but SMS does not. I think I am wrong in sending AT commands for SMS.

Comment: unsigned char *CTRLZ = 0x1A; is incorrect, should be unsigned char CTRLZ = 0x1A; (without the *) since it is not a string.  Then use putc instead of puts.  (Or make it a string with a proper trailing '\0')

Comment: Also the delays may be problematic. You might have to poll the module to see when it is ready to receive your message, or acknowledges a command.

Comment: puts() here is a user defined function... How it may b problematic??

Comment: Or define your Ctrl+Z string as `"\x1a"`.

Answer (score 1):

(While this answer perhaps might seem rude it is not meant to be. It is just a [`b)` style](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) answer).

---

You should **never, never, never, ever** use `delay`, `sleep` or similar to wait for the respose from the modem! In the same way you hopefully never would think of writing a web browser that ignores all responses the web server sends back to you, you should never think of writing a modem communication program that ignores all responses the modem sends back to you.

You **MUST** change your algorithm to the following:

```
send_at_command("AT+WHATEVER\r");
do {
    line = read_full_line();
} while (!is_final_result_code(line));
```

where read_full_line reads characher by character until it receives `\n` and the previous character was `\r` (assuming `V1` format<sup>1</sup>).

You can look at the code for [atinout](https://sourceforge.net/p/atinout/code/ci/master/tree/atinout.c) for an example for the is_final_result_code function (you can also compare to isFinalResponseError and isFinalResponseSuccess in [ST-Ericsson's U300 RIL](https://github.com/aferre/u300-ril/blob/master/atchannel.c), although note that CONNECT is not a final result code, it is an intermediate result code, so the name isFinalResponseSuccess is not 100% correct).

Also, specifically for AT+CMGS, you **MUST** wait for the `\r\n>`  response from the modem before you start sending the payload. See the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) for more details.

---

<sup>1</sup>
See *6.2.6 DCE response format* in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). You should not change this to V0, even if it might seem tempting to only having to check for a single character at the end of final result codes, but because information text have always `\r\n` as EOL, and you are just way better of treating all lines in the same way.